# overlay plots and keep 2 X axis

Tags: r, time-series

Is there a "automatic" way of adding a second x axis bellow the first one?

My data is similar to this:

```
A1=data.frame(dates=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by="day", length.out=1080),obs=runif(1080,min=-10,max=15))
A2=data.frame(dates=seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), by="day", length.out=1080),obs=runif(1080,min=-8,max=50))

par(new=T)
plot(A1,ylim=range(min(A1[,2],A2[,2]):max(A1[,2],A2[,2])))
par(new=F)
plot(A2,ylim=range(min(A1[,2],A2[,2]):max(A1[,2],A2[,2])))
```

The only solution I found was to make it by manually. I have multiple time series with the same length and I would like to overlay the observations and keep the x axis like this:

```
_________________________________________________
  |        |       |        |        |        |
2000     2001     2002     2003     2004     2005  
2010     2011     2012     2013     2014     2015
2020     2021     2022     2023     2024     2025
(...)
```

each time series with a different colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically? Not that I know of.

But I do know that you can (with some effort) do this by hand. For example:

```
par(mar = c(10,4,4,2) + 0.1)
plot(1:3,1:3,axes = FALSE,xlab = "")
axis(1,1:3,labels = FALSE)
mtext(c('2000','2001','2002'),side = 1,line = 1,at = 1:3,col = "red")
mtext(c('2010','2011','2012'),side = 1,line = 2,at = 1:3,col = "blue")
mtext(c('2000','2001','2002'),side = 1,line = 3,at = 1:3,col = "red")
mtext(c('2010','2011','2012'),side = 1,line = 4,at = 1:3,col = "blue")
axis(2)
```

[image]

I've increased the number of lines in the bottom margin to 10 by setting `mar`, to demonstrate how you'd ensure there's enough room for each row of axis labels.

Then you plot, omitting the axes, add the x axis with just the ticks, and then draw each row of text labels using `mtext`.

If you didn't need each row to be a different color, you could do this with one call to `axis` where the `labels` argument consists of a vector like `c("2000\n2010\n2020","2001\n2011\n2021","2002\n2012\n2022")` and then fiddling with `padj` to get them centered correctly.